# Pytest - get visibility of fixtures used and data created

Tags: python, pytest

I'm having issues with the performance of some pytests - some small tests taking minutes to complete. I've no doubt this is due to some fixture somewhere doing something unexpected, but we have a tonne of fixtures across our codebase, developed by multiple developers, and they use other fixtures, which use other fixtures etc. etc. So it is very hard to track down where a performance issue is occurring.

I am just wondering if there is any good way of getting some visibility of what fixtures were called or the state of the test DB? Apart from using print statements everywhere of course.